# How to set autocomplete attribute to off globally in project?

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, autocomplete

I am working on a `ASP.NET MVC` project that involves a lot of forms and `HTML` inputs. I am forced to set `autocomplete="off"` on each and every form in my project. I want to know of a way in which I can set this only once in the project and the project considers this for all the forms that are there in the project, and the forms that might be added in the future.

I am doing the following right now:

`<form id="myForm" asp-action="MyAction" asp-controller="MyController" autocomplete="off">`

Comment: Have you tried anything? I'm pretty sure you could solve it using javascript or Jquery.

Comment: I was thinking of adding it in Master Page, but my project does not have a Master Page.

Comment: Probably something as simple as this `$("input, select, textarea").attr("autocomplete", "off");`

Comment: Thank you Adam. I had guessed the same. But I was not sure where to add the code snippet as I do not have something (like a Master Page) that goes on top of all the pages.

Comment: You can just add it to the `<head>` section inside `<script></script>` tags. Be sure to add the Jquery CDN to the head section also.